Homebrew installs python, but not pip
I have installed python using Homebrew.
python3 --version

=> 3.11.7
pip3 --version

=> pip 23.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
When I am using pip3 to install something, this works fine, but I get at the end the suggestion:
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.3.1 -> 24.1.2
[notice] To update, run: python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip

Is it safe to update pip3 in the suggested way, or would this conflict with the way homebrew manages its installation?
BTW, I don't have a binary named pip, but only a pip3. Of course I can do a
ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip

if necessary.

I’ve got to ask the obvious question. What happens when you run the To update, run: command? It won’t matter to homebrew that you are using pip from the python it dropped.

Do you need to upgrade pip?

@MarcWilson : I don't know whether an upgrade of pip is advisable. I simply can ignore the warning as well.  I just wanted to know whether doing it with my suggested command, would conflict with the way homebrew manages its installed packages.
